# Change the foregroundcolor and background color using a string

Tags: c#

Im trying to change the background and foreground color by using a string.

```
Console.Write("Color:");
string backgroundcolor = Convert.Tostring(Console.ReadLine());
```

And then the background colors turns to the one i wrote

Comment: [This example could be useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.backgroundcolor?view=netframework-4.8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Console foreground/background colors can be set via the [Console.Foreground/BackgroundColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.backgroundcolor?view=netframework-4.8) property.

The available color options are defined in the [ConsoleColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor?view=netframework-4.8) enum.

We can set these values programmatically from a string value using [Enum.Parse/TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8).

Here's a quick example program that will set `Console.ForgroundColor` and `Console.BackgroundColor` based on the user's input (and give a warning if the specified value isn't a valid option)

```cs
class Program
{
    public static void Warn(string msg)
    {
        // get current color selections
        var currentFGColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        var currentBGColor = Console.BackgroundColor;

        // set warning colors
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

        Console.WriteLine($"{msg}");

        // set the colors back to the current selections
        Console.ForegroundColor = currentFGColor;
        Console.BackgroundColor = currentBGColor;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get foreground input
        Console.Write("Foreground Color: ");
        string foregroundColorString = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).Trim();
        // get background input
        Console.Write("Background Color: ");
        string backgroundColorString = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).Trim();

        if (Enum.TryParse(foregroundColorString, ignoreCase: true, out ConsoleColor _foregroundColor))
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = _foregroundColor;
        }
        else
        {
            Warn("- Invalid ForegroundColor option :(");
        }

        if (Enum.TryParse(backgroundColorString, ignoreCase: true, out ConsoleColor _backgroundColor))
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = _backgroundColor;
        }
        else
        {
            Warn("- Invalid BackgroundColor option :(");
        }

        // output to the console using the requested colors (assuming they were valid)

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```